# Update THIS value in an input with Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an input field that I need to adjust when a button is clicked for either plus or negative.  From documentation I've seen it would be something like a counter.
Where data would contain a variable counter and then I adjust that.  However here I have multiple items on the same page.  So if I have one "counter" then all would adjust.  How can I do this with multiple input values?  Code below:

```
    {% for itemDetail in cart.items %}
        <div>
          {{ itemDetail.variant.option3 }} {{ itemDetail.variant.option1 }}:  
          <div class="flex-container" style="padding: 5px;">
            <div class="flex-child">
              <button type="button" class="qty-add-sub-2" @click="updateQty( {{ itemDetail.quantity }}, {{ itemDetail.id }}, 'min' )">
                <span class="qty-minus">-</span>  
              </button>  
            </div>
            <div style="flex: 2;">
              <input class="qty-box-2" type="text" id="qty" name="qty" value="{{ itemDetail.quantity }}" >     
            </div>
            <div class="flex-child">
              <button type="button" class="qty-add-sub-2" @click="updateQty( {{ itemDetail.quantity }}, {{ itemDetail.id }}, 'add' )">
                <span class="qty-add">+</span>    
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

The cart.items loops in Ruby.

```
<input class="qty-box-2" type="text" id="qty" name="qty" value="{{ itemDetail.quantity }}" >   

value="{{ itemDetail.quantity }}" is the quantity when the cart loads.  However I need to put that when the button is clicked for either adding or minus.
```

I'm stuck on how to do this since each item is different.  There could be 20 inputs on the page when it's calculated as cart.items is unlimited.

I attempted to add a method in my vue script by doing a v-model like so:

```
<input class="qty-box-2" type="text" id="qty" name="qty" v-model="updateValItem"  @input="updateQty(`${ option.id }`, $event.target.value)" >  

   methods: {
      updateValItem() {
        return 10;
      }
    }
```

The value in the input displays: function () { [native code] }

Obviously I'm doing this wrong.  Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: v-model doesn't work this way. What is updateQty and how is it supposed to work together with updateValItem?

Comment: @EstusFlask updateQty immediately calls an ajax method and then refreshes the page so that itemDetail.quantity is then updated but the issue is that it lags slightly since it waits for the ajax call to complete.  I'd like to change the value insantly so that's why I wanted something like a method on value.

Comment: It would be `:value="updateValItem()"`. But you don't really need Vue for this. This is not how it works, it's not a glorified template engine

Comment: Ok got you.  I was already using vue in other areas that's why I thought about adding it with vue.  Thank you! @EstusFlask

Comment: You should assign your quantity value to a JS variable in Vue like this `let quantity = ref({{ itemDetail.quantity }})`. Then whenever you want to show/update the quantity, just use that variable `<input type="text" v-model="quantity">`